# RxJS timeout is not working

Tags: javascript, timeout, rxjs

I'm trying to exit the Observable stream when it takes longer than 3 seconds. The problem is that when I copy and paste the same value a couple of times, `distinctUntilChanged` operator does not let the input stream go passed. So I want to time out if no string stream comes passed it. Here is what I have.

```
        import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
        import "rxjs/add/operator/filter";
        import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
        import "rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged";
        import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";
        import "rxjs/add/operator/timeout";

        this._searchSubject
        .filter(val => val.length > 0)
        .debounceTime(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .timeout(3000)
        .switchMap(userSearchInput => {
            ...api call that returns Promise
        })
        .subscribe(searchResults => {
            ...do stuff with the result
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

A timeout throws a `TimeoutError`, are you handling this error?

```
Rx.Observable.from(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)))
  .timeout(500)
  .subscribe(console.log, ({ message }) => console.error(message));
```

Alternatively you can use `timeoutWith` & `Rx.Observable.empty()` to end the stream:

```
Rx.Observable.from(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)))
  .timeoutWith(500, Rx.Observable.empty())
  .subscribe(null, null, () => console.log('done'));
```

Comment: This code will completely silently ignore the error. The 'done' will get called but you won't be able to take explicit action. You're probably better off doing `timeoutWith(500, throwError('Service X took too long')).subscribe((val) => ok(val), (err) => err(err))` and then handling the timeout (or potentially other errors).